# Converting values in Map to List<Serializable> in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a `TreeMap` that contains `<String, Object>`. I'm looking to convert the values in the `TreeMap` to a `List<Serializable>` that contains a special value.

#### My Attempt

```
  private List<Serializable> getSecurityAttributes(
      Map<String, Object> inputTemplate, String securityAccess) {
    return inputTemplate
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj.getKey().contains(securityAccess))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .map(Serializable.class::cast)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

I'm getting a class cast exception and not quite sure why.

#### Specific Error:

> Cannot cast org.boon.core.value.ValueList to java.io.Serializable

Comment: It's because the value is not a String. You need to cast it to Serializable if it really is one

Comment: Does it need to cast to serializable? I thought since string implemented serializable I was fine.

Comment: You say you want a List<Serializable> but attempt to create a List<String>. Maybe change the line to `.map(Serializable.class::cast)`? Hard to say without seeing actual values.

Comment: Not all serializables are String. (example `Number`)

Comment: @RyanHack `I thought since string implemented serializable I was fine`. Casting is a "do what I say" and not a "do what I mean" process.

Comment: Your values are just `Object`s. So you need to cast or to convert to `Serializable` in some way.

Comment: Is it possible to change the method parameter type to `Map<String, ? extends Serializable> inputTemplate`?

Comment: Cannot cast org.boon.core.value.ValueList to java.io.Serializable Is my error when casting each item to serializable. So I am getting a ValueList on getValue().. So I need to somehow map over the values in the valuelist?

Comment: @RyanHack Neither ValueList, AbstractList or List implement or extend Serializable, that's why you get the ClassCastException. So the answer to your question in this particular case is: You can't.

Answer (score 1):

I casted the `ValueList` to a regular `List` and ran `flatMap` on it to cast each of the values.

```
  private List<Serializable> getSecurityAttributes(
      Map<String, Object> inputTemplate, String securityAccess) {
    return inputTemplate
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(obj -> obj.getKey().contains(securityAccess))
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .map(List.class::cast)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
```

Comment: `.map(Map.Entry::getValue) .map(List.class::cast) .flatMap(List::stream)` can be replaced with a single `.flatMap(e -> ((List)e.getValue()).stream())`; that long chain is a typical case of overusing method references.

Answer (score 0):

An Ojbect cannot necessarily be cast to a String (do not confuse calling `toString()` on an object, which is always possible and casting to a String which requires the object to be a subtype of String). For instance, running this: `System.out.println(String.class.cast(new Object()));` yields:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Object to java.lang.String
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at p493.Run493.main(Run493.java:42)
```

But `System.out.println(new Object().toString());` yields `java.lang.Object@2a139a55`.

I do not know what you are trying to do exactly but your code would run if you replace `.map(String.class::cast)` by `.map(Object::toString)`.

Comment: This is interesting. So I think this is getting closer to what I want. It's serializing the ValueList into a string, but I want to store each value in the value list as a string in this case. How can I go that extra step

Comment: String is final, it doesn't have subtypes